# Can I use xmlzipio to read xml from memory with xmlReadMemory?

Tags: c, io, xml-parsing, gzip, libxml2

I want to use [xmlzipio](http://hal.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/~christi/projects/xmlzipio.html) to read zipped xml files, but the problem is that I have to read them from memory and don't want to flush them to filesystem only to enable i/o functionality. Does xmlio.h affect xmlReadMemory behavior?

Comment: Do you have a zip-file _in memory_ (like downloaded from some site but not saved to disk) and want to use that? In that case why not use e.g. [libzip](http://nih.at/libzip/) to unzip the wanted file into another memory chunk, and then use `xmlReadMemory`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it may help, but I'm not familiar with libzip API -- zip_open needs filename as well, does libzip allow reading from memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a POSIX (Like Linux or Mac OSX) system, you could use e.g. [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_open.html) together with [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) to create a memory mapped dummy file. If you need a `FILE` pointer, then pass the descriptor returned by `shm_open` to [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fdopen.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand how to use it, because libxml2 parser functions cannot work with file descriptors and FILE* structs; xmlParseFile needs file name (not a descriptor or FILE* struct) as an argument. How can I use mmap together with shm_open to solve this problem?